# Double boiler sort of pan

Tags: equipment, stainless-steel

I have a stainless steel sort of double boiler made in Israel, but the top only has one cylindrical steam vent sticking up about 3 inches off center.  What would it be used for?

Comment: Welcome to the site Barbara. Any chance you could post a picture of the item in question?

Comment: From what I understand (we would thank a picture!), a double boiler you mean that the bottom part can have water or whatever, and the top part will get the heat/steam from the bottom part. If that's the case, that is the reason it needs the steam vent. It must go outside somehow